# Function specialization for arrays not being called

Tags: c++, arrays, function, declaration, specialization

I have a function which is templated on its argument:

```
template <class Vector>
void F(Vector& vec);
```

I want to add a specialization of this function for numeric arrays.  My attempt looks like this:

```
template <class NumType>
void F(NumType array[]);
```

I am having difficulty in calling the specialized function in the code.  See below:

```
void main()
{
  double a[] = {0.0, 1.0};
  F(a); // This calls the Vector version of the function,
        // with Vector = double [3], in my specific case.
}
```

If it helps, I do know beforehand that the function needs a length 3 array to work properly.

How do I fix my specialized function declaration so the NumType array version of the function is called?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
template <class NumType, size_t N>
void F(NumType (&array)[N]);
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked.  I will checkmark it when the system allows me to.

This is perfect for variable size arrays.  In my case, I could require a fixed size array.  Using your answer, I specialized mine to length three arrays

    template <class NumType>
    void F(NumType (&array)[3]);